# Add min and max to array of POROs

Tags: ruby

How can I add `min` and `max` methods to an array of POROs?

I have a class called `Sensor`

```
class Sensor 
 ...
end
```

And I wish to, given an array of sensors, be able to send the message `min` and `max` to retrieve what I consider the minimum and the maximum according to 2 different custom methods.

I suppose I have to override some methods (as I do when I need sorting) but I can find information about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask what are POROs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [max_by and min_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) methods

```
array_of_objects.max_by { |x| x.custom_method_in_object }
```

example

```
> ["a", "bb", "ccc"].max_by {|word| word.length } 
# => "ccc"
```

So, if you have `min` and `max` methods defined in `Sensor` class, you can call

```
array_of_sensors.max_by {|s| s.max } # Min can be done similarly
```

or using the shorcut

```
array_of_sensors.max_by &:max
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems to be the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to use Comparable module:

```
class Sensor
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    # Comparison logic here.
    # Returns -1 if self is smaller then other
    # Return 1 if self is bigger then other
    # Return 0 when self and other are equal
  end
end
```

Having this in place you can compare sensors with operators like `>`, `<`, `<=`. You can also sort an array of such the objects and use `max` and `min` methods.

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a

  include Comparable

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def <=>(other)
    self.a <=> other.a
  end
end

ary = [3,6,2,4,1].map{|a| A.new(a) }
ary.max       #=> #<A:0x000000027abc30 @a=6>
```